# Resize vcXsrv windows in WSL2

Tags: opencv, wsl-2, xserver

I am using **WSL2** with **VcXsrv** as X Server. More specifically, I am processing images using **opencv**. When I visualize an image, the window generated by the X server cannot be resized.
Can you help me fixing this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue here running a Qt desktop app on WSL2 Ubuntu through X server on Windows 10. I tested with VcXsrv, Xming and MobaXterm. Cannot drag, resize or maximize the window.